# Is it possible to create a thumbnail from a doc file as well as .xls file in ipad app

Tags: ipad, thumbnails, xls, doc

Is it possible to create a thumbnail from a  doc file as well as .xls file in ipad app..

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty sure that is possible yes.